# Existence of a relatively flat surface of $\mathbb{S}^3$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, surfaces, curvature, spheres

Consider $\mathbb{S}^3$ with the standard round metric.

Is there an embedded surface $S \subseteq \mathbb{S}^3$ with the following property:

> $R^{\mathbb{S}^3}(X,Y)=0$ for every two tangent vector $X,Y \in TS$.

That is, I require $R^{\mathbb{S}^3}(X,Y)Z=0$ for all $X,Y \in TS$ and $Z \in T\mathbb{S}^3$.

Here $R^{\mathbb{S}^3}$ is the Riemann curvature tensor of $\mathbb{S}^3$, not the curvature tensor of the induced Riemannian manifold $S$.

Is this condition related to other geometric properties like $S$ being a totally geodesic submanifold or a minimal submanifold?

Comment: Are you asking whether one can find an embedded surface in $S^3$ such that, when considered with the induced metric from the standard round metric it becomes flat? (has constant zero curvature)

Comment: No, that is not the question. I am using the curvature tensor of the *ambient manifold* $\mathbb{S}^3$, not the curvature tensor of the induced metric.

Comment: Do you want to require that $R(X,Y)Z = 0$ for all $X,Y \in TS$ and $Z \in TS$ or $R(X,Y)Z = 0$ for all $X,Y \in TS$ and $Z \in T\mathbb{S}^3$?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Now I understood you. I want to require $R(X,Y)Z=0$ for all $X,Y \in TS$ and $Z \in T\mathbb{S}^3$. By the way I guess both versions might be interesting. Do you see nice sufficient/necessary conditions for any of them? (or have any intuition?).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is negative, even if we only require that $R^{\mathbb{S}^3}(X,Y)Z=0$ for all $X,Y \in TS$ and $Z \in TS$. The standard metric on $\mathbb{S}^3$ has non-zero constant sectional curvature, and so $\langle R^{\mathbb{S}^3}(X,Y)X,Y \rangle \neq 0$.